# Using 14/3 to wire a fan and lights separately

Tags: wiring

I currently have 14/3 from my panel to a switch box.  The switch box has 2 switches, set up such that one switch would turn on the lights of fan/light combos, and the other switch turns on the fans.  From the switch box, I have run 14/3 to the location where I was going to hook up the light/fan combos.  Since running the wires, I have changed my mind, and would instead like to wire up a fan (no lights) and lights.  I have the 14/3 wire still sitting out, ready for use, but my question is: can I use the existing set up (the two separate switches and the 14/3) to wire a fan and string of lights separately such that one switch would turn on the lights and the other would turn on the fan?

I hope I explained that correctly.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. If an answer is helpful, please click the large check mark next to it to accept. And, please [take our tour](//diy.stackexchange.com/tour) so you'll know the details of contributing here.

Comment: This is done all the time.  No problem.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, that will work. Terminate the 14/3 (neutral and two switched hots) in the ceiling fan box where you'll hook up the neutral and a switched hot to the fan. Then connect the 14/2 for your light to the neutral in the fan box and to the other switch hot. Run the 14/2 to your light locations. You will naturally want to hook up all the ground wires to these fixtures.